# need to select photos marked as "public" or marked "for friends"

Tags: mysql

I need some solution to select photos which are marked as "public" or marked "for friends". I don't have an idea how is it possible.

Is it easy to select public photos:

```
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT filename, ownerid, etc... FROM photos 
WHERE public='1' order by id DESC limit $start, $step") or die('Error');
```

or even photos marked "for friends"

```
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT filename, ownerid, etc... FROM photos 
WHERE public='1' or for_friends='1' order by id DESC limit $start, $step") or die('Error');
```

But... each photo belongs to a different owner and before selecting them the query must know if I am a friend of the owner of this photo.

Comment: I can make/change table structure as needed. I just want an idea how to do this. I have "photos" table where filenames and owner ids are stored and I have a friends table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have a `friends` table which maps users with their friends, having columns `user_id` and `friend_user_id`, then your query should be something like this :

```
SELECT * 
FROM photos p 
WHERE p.owner_id IN (SELECT friend_user_id 
                     FROM friends 
                     WHERE user_id = 1234 ) 
  AND (p.is_public = '1' OR p.for_friends = '1');
```

Comment: I accept this answer but now I need to find some solution to get the same results without "or" statement.

Comment: Sorry i didn't get you? Is it just that your query shouldn't have `or` in it ?

Comment: "or" operator always causes problems with indexes. :(

Comment: Ah, that's tricky. Change your condition like this then : `NOT((NOT p.is_public='1') AND (NOT p.for_friends='1'))`

Comment: Thanks sub_stantial. I think I have to open a new question. I forgot some things. Each friend belong to a different friends group. There are public photos, photos for all friends and photos for a specific friends group. So, I need a query like this: WHERE public='1' or for_friends='1' or for_friends='$my_friend_group'. This makes everything even more complicated :(

Answer (score 0):

i guess you have a relation table which link users to users to match friends relationship

Then when you're a loggued, you have an user id.
Check if user id if a friend of picture owner.
If yes, request public pictures + friends pictures
else request only public pictures.

Comment: Yes, I have friends table but as I wrote before, each photo belongs to a different owner and BEFORE selecting them the query must know if I am a friend of the owner of this photo. I have 30 photos per page and each photo belongs to a different user.